# What design pattern would I use to pass one user choice to all classes where inheritance doesn't seem appropriate?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I am building a Python application which calculates sales, stock available and parts required which first asks a user to choose their department from a combobox.

What design should I use to best inform all classes within the application of the choice of department?  Once the department is chosen it remains used throughout the application and for the lifecycle of the application instance.

```
class Sales:

    def __init__(self, departmentname):
        self.departmentname = departmentname
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect(jsonhandler.get_json('connections.json'))


    def calculate_sales(self):
        with self.conn:
            departmentsalesvalues = pd.read_sql_query(f"""SELECT productcode, quantity, salesprice
                                      FROM salestable 
                                      WHERE department = ?""", self.conn, 
                                      params=(self.departmentname))
        return departmentsalesvalues
```

This works but it seems clumsy/a poor design.  I believe I am missing a concept/pattern which would be useful in all programming languages.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

The questions I have asked myself:
Should I create a Department class?  But because the department is not similar to the other classes in any way inheritance seems to be out of the question.
Should I pass this information around in a Main/App class? (Which is what i am currently doing.)
Should I have an 'orchestrator' class which interfaces with the Main/App class?

I am quite new to building scalable applications but I find this sort of design question occurring more and more in my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a variable that is used everywhere and for the life of the application I see two ways that will accomplish the task. 
A) Create a global variable (I know.. globals variables are *bad*. But for this particular scenario, when all you need is the department and you need it everywhere, a global variable is better than rewriting all of your classes to accept a constructor value)
B) Create a 'Context' class that has the department choice as a variable. The context item gets passed to all of your functions when they are called and you can add more information to the context class if need be.

For scalable applications, you would store this information in a 'configuration' file or in a special table in the database. 
You would then have context and middleware.

Context is a dictionary that is passed to all of your business functions.

Middleware is a list of classes that alter the context in some way.

You would have a middleware class called "UserChoices" that has a function:

```
def alterContext(context={}):
    context["DepartmentChoice"] = readDBvalue()
    return context
```

Then you would get the context like so

```
def getContext():
    context ={}
    for m in middlewares:
        context = m(context)
    return context
```

And then you can use your business functions like so

```
def businessFunc(context):
    return stuff
businessFunc(getContext())
```

Comment: *mutable* globals get worse and worse of a solution as the application grows larger and larger.  In the OPs case, the department choice is essentially a constant, so a global could  very well be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Parthanon many thanks. I feel inclined to avoid the 'global' solution and go with the middleware option.

Comment: @HarvB, no problem. :) If you're very serious about the scalability of your programs, you need to think about architecture before you even start coding. My recommended architecture for any scalable application is definitely MVC, and I'd do that by using Django (Or flask if you need more technical stuff) as a backend database essentially, then any UI framework that can handle http requests. This way you seperate the database and algorithms from the UI. So if you need to drastically change either of them in the future, it's easy :)